# How to fix 'The file .... does not exist in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I want to download file from storage folder in my Laravel project.

This is the method I'm using to download the file:

```
return response()->download(storage_path($path), $name);
```

When I click the link which redirects to this method I receive this output from the browser:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
>   The file "pathToTheFile" does not exist.

The problem is that when I go to www.mydomain.com/pathToTheFile, the browser shows me this txt file. Why doesn't it download the file from the link? Anyone can help?

The file is uploaded using Voyager Admin Package if it's important.

Comment: Where is the file being saved? Maybe you've got the wrong path.

Comment: Check the file on the disk, your path is def wrong. Most likely the file is stored in `storage/app/public`, and you are trying to do `storage_path()`, which is just `storage`. Check where exactly the file is uploaded, and use the correct path: `storage_path('app/public/FILE)`

Comment: The file is saved in standard Laravel storage folder. As I wrote when I copy the link which is visible in the error message to www.mydomain.com/COPIED-LINK the file appears in the browser... so it exists somehow and the path is correct.

Comment: @Raul I tried this solution but it's not working also.

Comment: `www.mydomain.com/COPIED-LINK` implies the file is stored in your `public` folder. Which is not in your `storage` folder. You might have a symlink or something, but if not, then you need to use `public_path($file)` to get your file.

Comment: I didn't have this problem when I was working localy. It appeared when I tried to deploy project to server. Maybe the problem is in my file structure? I' ve got domain which is connected with folder 'website' which contains Laravel public folder content and folder 'source' with all other files of the project. So the storage folder is in my root folder and the path to file is /storage/files/myFile.txt. The same path is shown in error message. I do the same thing with src of images on the website and it works great.

Comment: Maybe the link to the website will be helpful? http://miko.gawelkot.pl/products/1 You can see download section in 'DO POBRANIA' part.

Comment: On the live server, can you confirm where exactly are those files stored? Can you paste the path here? I mean, the error is clear, the path you are giving it is wrong. Maybe on your local  env you have some kind of symlink, which you do not have on live. I see that mentioned in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk).

Comment: I made a few changes so the structure is more clear. I've got my files in `~/storage/app/public/files`. I have symlink from `~/public/storage` to `~/storage/app/public`. My download method is `return response()->download(public_path('storage/'.$path));` where `$path = 'files\October2019\lBytlOtOnbNTHTHLmaFQ.txt'`

Comment: And something like this `<img src="storage/{{$ver->image}}>` works great. The image is visible.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem. The method should be:

`return Storage::disk('public')->download($path, $name);`

Thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location

Comment: this solution solved a 2-day problem for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

1.Method:

```
$filePath = public_path("storage/app/public/test.xlsx");
return response()->download($filePath);
```

get "file does not exist" error.

2.Method:

```
$filePath = public_path("storage/app/public/test.xlsx");
return Storage::disk('public')->download($filePath);
```

get "Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location" error.

3.Method: (Solution for me)

```
$filePath = storage_path('/app/public/test.xlsx');
return response()->download($filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many solutions and it says file does not exists.

At the end I just discovered that I forgot to add the file type:

```
 $subpath = 'pages/page' . $id . '.pdf';
    $path = storage_path("app/public/".$subpath);
    if (file_exists($path)){
        return response()->download($path);
    }else{
        abort(404);
    }
```